# Error Calling a WCF POST Restful Service from Angular JS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, rest, wcf

I am stuck in a strange issue where my GET WCF Restful APIs from AngularJS code is working fine but the POST request is not working. Below is my WCF Post Service Code:

Interface Code and Implementation:

```
[OperationContract]      
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "TestPost")]
string TestPost(string sValue);

public string TestPost(string sValue)
{
     return sValue;
}
```

Angular JS Client Code:

```
$scope.testPostAPI = function ()
{
    var data = $.param(
        {
            FName: "John",
            LName: "Smith"
        });

    var config =
        {
            headers:
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

    $http.post('http://localhost:5000/RestServiceImpl.svc/TestPost', data, config)
        .success(
        function (data, status, headers, config)
        {                        
            $scope.DOCUMENTSAVERESPONSE = data;  
            $scope.ResponseDetails= 'Response from post service'
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config)
        {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;
        });
}
```

Comment: It seems that parameter of the POST API is not matched. Your API has parameter as a string and from Angular, you are passing the object with Fname & Lname.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but perhaps the content type should be specified as "application/json" if the body contains the payload.

Comment: I am getting the below error after changing the contentType 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a complex type from the client to an enpoint expecting a simple type. You have two options.

1 Send the "John Smith" over as a simple type string.

2 Change your formal parameters on your api method to take a Person, for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FName{get;set;}
    public string LName{get;set;}
}


public Person TestPost(Person sValue)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but still no luck with the first option. I am getting Http error HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use content type as : application/json and then before passing the data values
use JSON.stringify(data)

$http.post('http://localhost:5000/RestServiceImpl.svc/TestPost', JSON.stringify(data), config)
            .success(
            function (data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $scope.DOCUMENTSAVERESPONSE = data;
                $scope.ResponseDetails= 'Response from post service'
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config)
            {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "

---

status: " + status +
                    "

---

headers: " + header +
                    "

---

config: " + config;
            });

Comment: I tried doing this but still no luck. I am getting Http error HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed.